# Bad mapping with @GeoPointField Elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i'm using spring-boot 1.5.1 with Elasticsearch 2.3.5 (for Mahout Recommender system), so i have a problem with mapping:

```
@GeoPointField
private GeoPoint location;
```

From package:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo;
```

So, by [localhost:9200/.../.../_mapping?pretty=1](http://localhost:9200/.../.../_mapping?pretty=1) i have:

```
location: {
  properties: {
   lat: {
     type: "double"
   },
   lon: {
     type: "double"
   }
  }
}
```

But, i want **geo_point** type for location field.

As a result, when i trying:

```
CriteriaQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(new Criteria("location").within(startLocation, range));
```

I have:

```
QueryParsingException[failed to find geo_point field [location]]
```

Does anybody knows the solution?
Thx

Comment: I have the same configuration and had the same problem. I removed all ElasticSearch files and when I then created the entities, they received the correct mapping.

Comment: I have same problem, did you find any solution with spring data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your mapping. It should be **geo_point** type. e.g.
You can do it with [curl PUT](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type' -d '
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {

          "phone": {
        "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
    },
    "webSite": {
        "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
    "location": {
        {"type":    "geo_point"}            
    }
  }
}
'
```

When saving the data, you can do:

```
"location":{
    "lat":11.68036,
    "lon":-93.3103
}
```

Comment: Ok :)
@Hosar, I know that the problem is my mapping, but how i can resolve it with using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Comment: You can do it with curl, not sure how to do it with Spring.